# Windows Phone If Canvas Fill Color Equals Color

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-phone

I am pretty a newby. So what i want to do is to switch the color of a canvas element, when tappnig on it. I already can change it one time. Now i want to change it back, when i tap on it a second time.

here are the lines

```
<Canvas x:Name="N" Width="339.667" Height="349" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
   <Path x:Name="Path" Width="94" Height="89" Canvas.Left="118.833" Canvas.Top="-7.62939e-006" Stretch="Fill" Fill="White" Tap="Tap_N" Data="F1 M 165.833,-7.62939e-006L 212.833,89L 165.333,68L 118.833,89L 165.833,-7.62939e-006 Z "/>
</Canvas>
```

and

```
 private void Tap_N(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Path.Fill.Equals(Colors.White))
        {
            SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
            mySolidColorBrush.Color = Colors.Transparent;

            System.Windows.Shapes.Path Path = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)sender;
            Path.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
        }
        else
        {
            SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
            mySolidColorBrush.Color = Colors.White;

            System.Windows.Shapes.Path Path = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)sender;
            Path.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
        }
    }
```

so i know, that i cant do it with that Path.Fill.Equals. but how can i ask, if exactly this canvas path is filled with this or that color. 
i also read something about

```
public override sealed bool Equals(Object obj)
```

do i have to solve it this way? if yes, then how would it work?
hope you get the idea, and i hope someone can help me out, as i said i am pretty new to this.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `Path.Fill.Equals(Colors.White)` is always `false`, because it compares objects of two different types. `Path.Fill` is of type `Brush`, whereas `Colors.White` is of type `Color`.

You may strongly simplify your code by creating a SolidColorBrush in XAML and check and update its `Color` in code behind:

```
<Path Tap="Tap_N" ...>
    <Path.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
    </Path.Fill> 
</Path>
```

Code:

```
private void Tap_N(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var path = (Path)sender;
    var fill = (SolidColorBrush)path.Fill;

    if (fill.Color == Colors.White)
    {
        fill.Color = Colors.Transparent;
    }
    else
    {
        fill.Color = Colors.White;
    }
}
```